# include file conflict resolution

Tags: c++

I have a C++ project that I am building on Linux using g++. I have two "include directories" that I have to add as arguments using -I. The problem is that in each of these directories, I have some overlapping and common files. Thus when I have

```
g++ -o program program.cpp -I/foo/include -I/bar/include
```

I get compiler warnings like so:

```
stdint.h:174:0: warning: "__UINT64_C" redefined [enabled by default]
#define __UINT64_C(c)     c ## ULL
```

What is the best way I can include files selectively so that I do not face issues like this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you have overlapping and common files in two places in your project?

Comment: They are references to include directories in two different libraries

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be due to overlapping or common files but to overlapping definitions.

Comment: Yes there are overlapping definitions as a result of common files. I was wondering if there is a way that can be avoided by only picking selective files from the included directories.

Comment: Why is one of your libraries messing with a name that is reserved to the implementation? Anything that begins with double underscore should not appear in any library.

Comment: @Alan Stokes The error message that you see is what I'm actually getting. The include directories are directories within the android-ndk. I have some files that are missing in one of the libraries that are being used in another. I am actually modifying a Makefile of a certain project which already has the second include library (with overlaps) and makes references to files only in the ndk installation on my hdd.

Comment: "overlapping definitions as a result of common files". Dubious. It's not like both files are being included.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems seems to be more due to overlapping definitions than files that happen to have the same name. But either way, I'd suggest the following fix:

Don't use files from both of these libraries in the same file in your application. Have some files that use the first library and some that use the second. Files that use the first library are compiled with its include path. Files that use the second library are compiled with its include path.

If you really need to integrate calls to both libraries in the same code, just wrap one or both libraries with a sanitized interface whose file and identifier names don't conflict with your project's names.

Comment: I agree with this in general.  But in some cases, depending on the architecture of the files, you might be able to just wrap the `#include` statements in individual `namespace` blocks to separate the conflicting declarations without having to re-structure your code/project, eg: `namespace libA { #include <libA.h> } ... namespace libB { #include <libB.h> }`